# Which Windows 8 tool should I use to "read", "upload", my Windows 7 latest backup DVD (is it possible?)

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-8

Which Windows 8 tool should I use to "read", "upload", my Windows 7 latest backup DVD (is it possible?).

I've just installed W8 and haven't made any changes to my new ecosystem and, what happened was that, as I was managing my new drivers, some mess* occurred, I confess, and now what I have left is every single backup tool I made use of W7, like system images, restore dvds, backup up to date monthly and so on, and would like to keep in touch with W8.

I'm one of those with problems managing the amd switchable gpu drivers. Now I want to stay with W8 (download version - didn't clean install) but with my old personal files. I don't care to programs updates. I got everything original on dvds, of my interest. Yesterday I tried refreshing W8 once but didn't work. Maybe trying again tonight.

What would you guys do in my place, please?

*the mess I am talking about is to have disabled my intel (the only driver left) gpu in device manager tool in W8. I got black screen on system boot.

Please, take a look at comments below!

Cheers, C.C.

Comment: How did you make the backup?

Comment: What exactly is your question.  You read your backup DVD the same was you created, using the tool, that created it.  If you used the built-in one it still exists in Windows 8.

Comment: Like I said, thru windows 7 backedup monthly. On DVD disc.

Comment: My question is: is w8 compatible with my W7 backedup DVD disc? How can I restore my personal files when restoring my W8, what I'm thinking of doing soon. Any suggestion besides this?

Comment: I didn't save my files on DVD, burning it (manually, selecting, copying them, pasting files, no). instead I used the backup tool in windows 7.

Comment: If you used Windows 7's backup to make it, then have you tried using Windows 8's backup/restore yet?  What happened when you tried?

Comment: last thing I did last night was trying to refresh W8, keeping my already installed personal files in W8. Didn't try to restore because my files are still there but I got the black screen, you see? If I restore W8, I'll lose my files and need to be sure that the DVD will be read by clean W8, see? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is compatible with Windows 8, insert the dvd into the drive on the windows 8 PC, then open Windows Explorer and browse the dvd, there will be a file on there named after your "computer name" of the PC you made the backup on, DV6T in my case.

Double click that file and follow the prompts.

[image]

.

[image]

.

Here you will see all your backup versions (dates), there is only one on my test restore shown below.

[image]

.

If you have several backups,  I ticked the "select all files from this backup", but you could browse and select on certain files if you want. If yuo select the "Browse for files" button it will open a file browser and you can see all your backed up files and folders to select what you want to restore.

[image]

.

[image]

.

Here you can choose where to restore them to.

[image]

.

[image]

.

Here is a screenshot of the files restored to my C drive in the original location C:\backup

[image]

Comment: Really apreciate this! Thanks. Yesterday, I started a clean install of Windows again. I hope AMD releases an update for its HD 4500 series mobility radeon switchable drivers soon. And at least, that the code that I got when bought new W8 thru download works when I will try reinstalling it, because I got failure and had to get back to W7, default OS in my laptop. Cheers, C.